# Push footer to bottom of page without using "positition: absolute; bottom: 0"

Tags: html, push, footer

So I'm trying to have my footer in the bottom of the page at all time without using "position: absolute" as it overlaps the content of the page when the screen gets smaller. I also do not want to use "position: fixed" as I do not want the footer to be visable at all times. When I use "position: relative" it creates a white space below the footer and I cannot remove it. I would be very grateful if you could help me. I'm currently using Bootstrap 4 for my project. Here's my code:

```
<div class="container">
(some content)
</div>
<footer>
(some content)
</footer>
```

css

```
footer {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use position fixed instead of absolute with fixed the footer always at bottom of the page. And bottom 0 then it will always be at bottom. If anything overlap the footer then you can do z-index to 100 or higher so nothing will overlap the footer.

Answer (score 0):

compare document.scrollingElement.scrollHeight and window.innerHeight in js.

if they are equal then that means your content is less than the view port in terms of height and you can use position absolute at bottom for footer as it wont override with your actual content.

if document.scrollingElement.scrollHeightis great than window.innerHeight then that means your content is bigger than the view port so without worrying you can place the footer at the bottom without using position property.

If window resizing is your problem (resizing may change height of your document) then you can use resize event listener on window. There you can call a function to do above mentioned steps.

Comment: Hi! Could you please elaborate? I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: document .scrollingElement.scrollHeight gives you height of your HTML document.  window.innerHeight gives you height of view port(area on which html will be shown). If scroll height is not great than inner height then that means your html document doesn't cover the whole area of browser. So in that case you can use  position : absolute for footer. As the content of webpage is less than the view port, your content won't override with browser.

Comment: If scrooling height is great that inner height then that means your html document has more height than the viewport. In that case your can put your footer at the end of html code which will automatically come at the bottom without using position : property. And as scrolling height is greater in this case, footer won't be hanging in middle.